# Nameserver and Domain config in WHM/Cpanel

Tags: domain-name-system

Just installed a fresh CPANEL/WHM on a VPS.

I only have one IP address.  What is the correct way to setup nameservers in WHM so that I can point the registered domains (i.e. from namecheap or godaddy or similar) to the nameservers at the server?

Alternatively, is it better to use the nameservers at the registrar and point the the domain directly to the new ip address that's registered in CPanel?

Comment: Administration panels are off-topic on Server Fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit the name server IPs at your domain registrar control panel. Most registrars allow to have two name servers in with the same ip. You can set up private name servers pointing to your server; like

```
ns1.yourdomain.com >> your_server_ip
ns2.yourdomain.com >> your_server_ip
```

By doing this your domain will start resolving to your server. Then you need to have proper entries in your named.conf. This can be done using the cpanel. Do let us know if you have further queries.

Comment: @Augustine - Indeed, I have done that.  I think my larger issue is setting it up in WHM and Cpanel...  THIS is where I'm basically clueless.